# How to Start programming for API testing with POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, postman, web-api-testing

Currently i have started to work with API testing with postman. But also i don't know java script and i don't know where to start with java script for Postman programming.I'd be cool if someone gave me hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

[Here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox) you can find all libraries and functions available in POSTMAN.

Comment: thanks dude...
I don't want to Write APIs......
I'm testing APIs via Postman....
In postman - in the pre-request script and testing scripts, we use javascript to manipulate data. so in those places - i want to know what kind of library used - or some information related to scripting in postman.

Comment: Oh okay ! [Here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox) you can find all libraries and functions available in POSTMAN.
 Is it what you tried to find ?

Comment: hoo woow.. Thanks broo.. I'll start from here.......

Comment: @nandha Super! I'm going to edit my post and please validate my answer ;)